# mysql query to get the numeric part of a field

Tags: database

I have a column in a table that has numbers and letters (not in any particular order) and i need to use an SQL query within a drupal module to get only the numeric part . How can I do this? the problem is there is no telling where the number starts or ends and where the letters start or end.  Is there a regex command ?  How can I do this in the query format that drupal requires?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) command (most if not all DBMSs have an equivalent), but Drupal doesn't have any special methods to use it per se.

The only difference is instead of using fields/field, you'll use addExpression to add it to the selected fields for the query, e.g.

```
$alias = $query->addExpression("col REGEXP '[0-9]+'");
```